# La manera correcta de hacer un Schema con Mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy creando una Base de Datos, donde tengo **Usuarios** y cada usuario puede añadir todos los productos que quiera, esos productos solo lo puede ver el usuario que lo crea.

Expongo los dos tipos de Schema que se me ocurre;

**1º =>**

Tener un solo Schema de la siguiente forma;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  productos: {
   nombre: String,
   cantidad: String
  }
})
```

**2º =>**

Tener dos Schema de la siguiente forma;

productos.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

  let productoSchema = new Schema({
    producto: { type: String, required: [true, 'El nombre es necesario'] },
    usuario: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Usuario' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Producto', productoSchema);
```

usuario.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let usuarioSchema = new Schema({

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El correo es necesario']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'La contraseña es obligatoria']
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Usuario', usuarioSchema);
```

Teniendo en cuenta que cada usuario tendrá muchos productos, **¿Cuál es la mejor manera de hacer la Base de Datos?**

Gracias.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *la manera correcta*? Eso siempre va a depender de cómo vayas a consumir la información de tu base de datos. A primera vista la segunda opción que planteas sería la más adecuada, sin embargo yo me lo pensaría. Por ejemplo, ¿un producto puede ser introducido por más de un usuario? Entiendo que cada usuario tiene acceso a sus propios productos, por lo tanto hay una diferencia entre un producto introducido por el usuario *A* y el mismo producto introducido por el usuario *B*, asumiendo que los productos se pueden repetir por usuario. ¿Puedes aclarar un poco más? Saludos

Comment: Todos los nombres de los productos se podrían repetir, pero aunque se repitan, cada usuario solo podrá acceder a los productos que ellos creen, aunque se llamen igual, se crearía un nuevo producto con el id del usuario. Para el proyecto es necesario que sea así. Con la manera correcta, quiero decir, con qué método mí Base de Datos estará mejor optimizada. Gracias.

Comment: Pues entonces la segunda opción parece ser la más adecuada (en mi opinión). Tendrías una colección de productos todos diferentes entre sí. Cada producto estaría relacionado con un usuario mediante la referencia apropiada. Las consultas las puedes realizar filtrando dicha referencia. Al momento de crear un producto, debes pasar el valor del campo `_id` del usuario que está creando el producto. Por lo tanto suena bien el planteamiento que formulas en tu segunda opción.

Comment: Si Mauricio, el id del usuario lo paso verificando el login del usuario. Gracias.